# I am having an issue uploading an app to the app store using Transporter from an ipa file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

I have built an archive of my app and tried uploading it to the App Store via the Transporter app and received the following errors:

- Asset validation failed (90125) The binary is invalid. The encryption
  info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or
  invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not
  seem to have been built with Apple's linker. (ID:
  bc23e124-393d-4d76-808a-bc6210ed3ec6)
- Asset validation failed (90124) The binary is invalid. The executable
  'SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion'
  has type 'OBJECT' that is not valid. Only 'EXECUTE' is permitted.
  (ID: 72f0c893-5a3c-44e3-a3df-a99a865da148)
- Asset validation failed (90635) Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in
  bundle
  "SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework"
  isn’t consistent with the Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle
  Mach-O contains arm64(bitcode), while the nested bundle Mach-O
  contains armv7(machine code) and arm64(machine code). Verify that all
  of the targets for a platform have a consistent value for the
  ENABLE_BITCODE build setting. (ID:
  ec0e4719-e744-494f-b06a-728fa3f452bc)
- Asset validation failed (90360) Missing Info.plist value. A value for
  the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle
  SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework
  is required. (ID: 1eb5a712-e7eb-45ca-b03a-5dc6a910b709)
- Asset validation failed (90210) Missing load commands. The executable
  at
  'SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework'
  does not have the necessary load commands. Try rebuilding the app
  with the latest Xcode version. If you are using third party
  development tools, contact the provider. (ID:
  62b18a6c-5b1b-4864-b502-4f37b19369b1)
- Asset validation failed (90125) The binary is invalid. The encryption
  info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or
  invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not
  seem to have been built with Apple's linker. (ID:
  0165171c-7862-40c9-b556-35e18aaeef76)
- Asset validation failed (90208) Invalid Bundle. The bundle
  SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework
  does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist.
  (ID: 8dbc7abc-78ff-4574-aa81-15bebe78c34b)
- Asset validation failed (90124) The binary is invalid. The executable
  'SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion'
  has type 'OBJECT' that is not valid. Only 'EXECUTE' is permitted.
  (ID: 753f8e15-45a7-406c-a1c5-e03762302ace)
- Asset validation failed (90081) This bundle is invalid. Applications
  built for more than one architecture require an iOS Deployment Target
  of 3.0 or later. (ID: 7c68b55d-79ce-46cd-93a4-2469416da09e)
- Asset validation failed (90171) Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary
  file
  'SpartanTutors.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework/GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion'
  is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or
  libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported
  bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at
  https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information
  on the iOS app bundle structure. (ID:
  e9e049e3-a2a2-4f92-9fa5-1155fcc3caeb)

I know there are a ton of errors but if anyone knows how to solve even a single one of them, help me out. It would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you,

Have a nice day!

Comment: "I have built an archive of my app and tried uploading it to the App Store via the Transporter app" You cannot upload an archive. You need to export for the App Store.

Comment: the issues seems like libraries duplication or something like that! you should remove all the dependencies and pods then install them again after cleaning the build then archive it with arm64